# How to use MySQL query to Twilio SMS phone based on results

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using the Twilio API to send broadcast SMS messages based on an approved number. The problem in which I have encountered is not being able to successfully run a query pulling the phone information from a database and enter it into the API for each results that meet the query criteria to send an SMS to. The below is what I have so far.

```
    //Include the PHP TwilioRest library
    require "Services/Twilio.php";

    //Set our AccountSid and AuthToken
    $AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    $AuthToken = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

   //Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

//Trusted numbers that we want to be able to send a broadcast

    $trusted = array("+33333333333" => "ApprovedAdmin1");

//An unauthorized user tried to send a broadcast.

    if(!$name = $trusted[$_REQUEST['From']])

    {header("content-type: text/xml");echo "\n";echo "Unauthorized broadcaster, contact an admin for access.";exit(0);}

//These are the recipients that are going to receive the broadcasts

//database user credentials  
    `$user = "user";`  
    `$password = "password";`  
    `$database = "database";` 
    `$host = "localhost";`  
//connect to the database  
    `$DB = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Can't connect to database.");`  
    `@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");`

//Used to query database for only user phone numbers who accept texts

    $recipients = array (mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM sms WHERE (accept_text = 'Y')"));

//I have commented this out to try to get the query to work. The below recipients array does work and even lists the names of the user in the SMS.

    //$recipients = array("+22222222222" => "testuser1");

//Grab the message from the incoming SMS

    $msg = $_REQUEST['Body'];

// Iterate over all our recipients and send them the broadcast

    //foreach ($recipients as $number => $name) {

//Send a new outgoinging SMS by POSTing to the SMS resource

    $sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create("3333333333",$number,"$name, " . $msg);echo $name . " ";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so first of all you are not executing valid XML on the error condition e.g. if the user is not a trusted number. If you want to reply to the texter that the number is unauthorised you would need to do:

```
header("content-type:text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<Response>\n<Sms>Unauthorized broadcaster, contact an admin for access.</Sms>\n</Response";
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the query - why is it in an array? And I don't know why you then have a recipients array - surely this is what you are pulling in from the database? You need to do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM sms WHERE accept_text = 'Y'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $client->account->sms_message->create("3333333333", $row['phone'], $_REQUEST['Body']); 
}
```

Comment: The XML validity works fine. The result variable isn't pulling from the table or responding to any number. If I run the query directly connected to the db the results pull fine.

Comment: If you are trying to use TwiML to respond to the user then your XML is not correct. It is not valid TwiML.

Comment: I'm using Twilio Rest. If the array is hard coded the respond sends just not from the db results itself.

Comment: Yes I know you are - but you are also outputting XML to the browser and given you are using $_REQUEST['From'] it sounds like you have told Twilio to use this script as your handler for SMS text messages. As such if you want the user to get the error text message back you must be using valid TwiML.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs to see if the script is throwing up any errors?

Comment: Ok. I'm able to get the error text back so, then if I'm using TwiML, how can I get the results from the query to send the broadcast text to each result using valid XML?

Comment: I get the general error from Twilio:  Error on line 2 of document : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. Please ensure that the response body is a valid XML document.

Comment: You have to use TwiMl only for the error message and then, if there is no error, you should use the REST api. Which is what I have done in my answer above. Somewhere in your script there must be an error - so I would check your error logs to find it.

Comment: Thats because your not using valid Twiml - use what I said above.

Comment: I have used what you said above exactly in the script. I only get the error when trying to pull from the database. Would that mean that the error would be in the result query?

Comment: Maybe - but all errors should be put into your apache error logs (if your using apache)

Comment: I finally got it to work. In your query an s on the Twilio instance creation was missing. Thank you for your work!    $result = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM sms WHERE accept_text = 'Y'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $client->account->sms_messageS->create("3333333333", $row['phone'], $_REQUEST['Body']); 
}